# Layout in QT designer

Tags: qt, layout, designer

In **qt designer**, I added a grid layout. then I made the main window to grid layout. see fig below.

[image]

then I added 2 vertical layouts inside the grid layout. see fig below

[image]
now the problem is that i can not change the size of 2 vertical layouts. I just wanted width of one of them to be 1/3 and the other to be 2/3. but the back to origin and they are always half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the way the layout is 
stretched or distributed, for that there is the property `layoustretch`, in the doc especified https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html as  [stretch factor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#stretch-factors)
 \

you can give a try and set that 1,2 and see that the whole layout is distributed to a proportion of 33% to the left part and 66% for the right part.

Comment: it was my pleasure!!